# Convert two lists to a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a LINQ function that could replace my two loops here to produce a similar result:

```
public class Outer {
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class Inner {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OuterId { get; set; }
}

var outers = new List<Outer>();
var inners = new List<Inner>();
// add some of each object type to the two lists

// I'd like to replace this code with a LINQ-style approach
var map = new Dictionary<long, long>();
foreach (Outer outer in outers) {
    foreach (Inner inner in inners.Where(m => m.OuterId == outer.Id)) {
        map.Add(inner.Id, outer.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your sample code may not do what you want it to...

Comment: The inner.Id will be unique no matter what. And each inner can only ever belong to one outer.  I have this properly working already, but I'm just looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is it really worth it?  It doesn't look like you need lazy execution, or any of the other linq-specific features.

Comment: @AdamLevitt Your solution is elegant to me, and easier to debug (before you replaced the `if` statement by the LINQ one).

Answer (score 5):

```
var map = inners
          .ToDictionary(a => a.Id, 
                        a => outers
                             .Where(b => b.Id == a.OuterId)
                             .Select(b => b.Id)
                             .First()
                        );
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `Type` of map resulting in `Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<Inner>>`? I could put a `select` on the end I suppose. But this is not down vote worthy.

Comment: No, I'm referring about comparing `b.OuterId` (a `long`) with `a` (`Outer`). Did you mean `b.OuterId == a.Id`?

Comment: This answer is actually backwards, which I fixed in my code manually, but in the value part of each KVP, I'm getting the full Outer object instead of its Id.

Comment: @AdamLevitt Edited my answer based on your comment. Hope this is an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Enumerable.Join and Enumerable.ToDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (writing test cases now):

```
var map = inners.Join(outers, x => x.OuterId, x => x.Id, (inner, outter) => new
    {
        InnerId = inner.Id,
        OuterId = outter.Id
    }).ToDictionary(x => x.InnerId, x => x.OuterId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict = (for outer in outers
            join inner in inners
            on outer.Id equals inner.OuterId
            select new KeyValuePair<long,long>(inner.Id, outer.Id)).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```